# Python xpath => SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler

I am a newbie to python. I'm trying to crawl some text, but it doesn't work...
Here is my code

```
    def parse(self,response):

    hxs = Selector(response)
    article_list = hsx.xpath('//*[@id="weather"]')

    print('##################### total_length : ' + str(len(article_list)))

    for a in article_list:
        html_response = HtmlResponse(uurl="", body=a.encode('utf-8') #??
        seoul = html_response.xpath('//dl[@class="po_seoul"]//dd[@class="temp"]')[0].extract()
```

and this is the html code.

```
            <h1 class="blind">weather_data</h1>
            <div id="weather" class="weather" >
                <dl class="po_seoul">
                    <dt>seoul</dt>
                    <dd class="weather"><a href="#" onclick="showLandForecast('1159068000'); return false;" data-stn="108"><img src="/images/icon/NW/NB04.png" alt="cloud" /></a></dd>
                    <dt class="blind">temperature</dt>
                    <dd class="temp">21.2</dd>
                </dl>
```

Error message:

`seoul = html_response.xpath('//dl[@class="po_seoul"]//dd[@class="temp"]')[0].extract()
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

plz help me...T0T

Comment: `html_response = HtmlResponse(uurl="", body=a.encode('utf-8')` you are missing closing parentheses in this line.

Comment: i've just fixed it and it work! thank you :D!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `)` after `HtmlResponse(uurl="", body=a.encode('utf-8')` it should be

```
HtmlResponse(uurl="", body=a.encode('utf-8'))
                                            ^
```

instead of what you have